# Evaluate methods across datasets based on distance metrics

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, model-evaluation, ranking, method-comparison

I want to evaluate $n$ methods, says $M_1,\cdots,M_n$ on $m$ datasets $D_1, \ldots, D_m$. For each method $M$, I have a score function $f(M,D) \in [0, \infty)$  for dataset $D$. A perfect method will have $f(M,D) = 0$ for all $D$, and the large score the worse the method. So a good method would have very small score across all datasets. Let's take an example, assume that a method $M$ is to approximate dataset $D$ by $D'$, and $f(M,D) = ||D- D'||$.

My questions are how to compare all methods over all datasets using score $f$. By comparison I mean to rank all methods by some meaningful criteria or to make a conclusion which methods work well. A trivial way to do it is to average score over all datasets and rank them. Better method would have smaller score. However because the score can be very large, a bad instance would strongly influence the average score and we would give the wrong conclusion even though a method is very good overall. I also think maybe we can rank methods for each dataset and use some test statistics to rank them. Since I have no knowledge on statistics I would like to ask for your suggestion. Maybe there already exists some test statistics to measure such a task. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be underspecified. As described, there might not even be chance involved and you do not mention any underlying distributions. Furthermore, it is not clear what kind of overall performance criteria are important. So here are some very generic/general ideas.

You want to decouple the ranking from the scores, due to outliers. Furthermore the scores for different datasets might have very different characteristics. I think this makes a lot of sense. So instead of using the scores themselves, you might want to use their ranks. I.e. for each dataset $j, j=1,\ldots, m$ you assign to method $i, i=1\ldots,n$ the rank $r_{ij}$, where $r_{ij}=1$ if the score $f(M_i, D_j)$ is lowest, 2 when it is second best and so on.

To obtain an overall ranking, you need to decide what is important to you. For example:

- Average case performance: then the overall rank of method $i$ is $R_i=\frac{1}{m}\sum_j r_{ij}$
- Worst case performance: then the rank is $R_i=\max_j r_{ij}$.

Of course there are obvious and endless variations (such as weighted ranks, squared deviations, ...).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! These datasets do not have any distribution and you can't assume so because they are of different types and measurements.  And as I already mentioned good solution will have small score ~ 0.

Comment: Yes, I did not phrase it well. You have a score $f$ for each "trial". But in determining the overall score across trials you need to trade off the single trials.

Answer (score 0):

The average of all results would be the "mean score" $\bar{F}(M)$
the problem you're describing with some data sets being outliers might be mitigated by using standard deviation (std) - $$\sigma(M)^2 = \sum(F(M,D)-\bar{F}(M))^2$$

Then you can use the mean divided by the standard deviation as a criterion for your methods, and rank them accordingly : $$C(M) = \dfrac{\bar{F}(M)}{\sigma(M)}$$

You could also plot out both mean and std to get insight into what makes your methods/data sets outliers.

Comment: I am not sure if it's a good ranking score because it will give high score to a method which has high and similar score. Theoretically, this is not a good method.

Comment: Hmm, maybe a more intricate version: mean(F/(F-mean(F))^(2*a)) where F=F(M,D) and you can control a>1. This way you lower the impact of methods which are significantly further from the mean.